# Error when trying to List.Sort();

Tags: c#

I have this method that creates and returns a list of strings and then should sort the strings alphabetically. I get an error (Cannot implicitly convert type `void` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>`) when I try this code:

```
public static List<string> ReturnListofFirstandLastName()
{
    List<string> names = new List<string>();

    Reademployeelist();
    for (int i =0; i < employeelist.Count;i++)
    {
        names.Add(employeelist[i].first_name + " " + employeelist[i].last_name);
    }

    return names.Sort();
}
```

Comment: `Sort` performs the sort inline, it returns `void`. What you want to do is `names.Sort(); return names;`

Comment: Or alternatively `return names.OrderBy(z => z).ToList();`. Also, consider moving the first line of code to just before the `for` loop so you can pre-allocate the size -> `List<string> names = new List<string>(employeelist.Count);`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `Sort` will simply sort the `IEnumerable`, but it does not return anything (which is different than `OrderBy()`, which returns a new `IEnumerable`).

The easiest way to solve this would be to just call `Sort` on the list, and then return it:

```
    // Previous code omitted

    names.Sort();
    return names;
}
```

---

As a side note, you might want to consider renaming some of your objects. For starters, property names are typically PascalCase (not words separated by underscores). So your employee class wouldn't have a `first_name`, but instead `FirstName`.

For example:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Also, your `employeelist` can just be called `employees` (typically collection types are simply named the plural of what the contained type represents), and `Reademployeelist` might be better named something like `PopulateEmployees` (reading implies that it reads the list, but since you call this before iterating over the list it appears that it's actually populating the list)?

```
private static List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

private static void PopulateEmployees()
{
    employees = new List<Employee>
    {
        new Employee {FirstName = "Warren", LastName = "Buffett"},
        new Employee {FirstName = "Jeff", LastName = "Bezos"},
        new Employee {FirstName = "Larry", LastName = "Page"},
        new Employee {FirstName = "Mark", LastName = "Zuckerberg"},
        new Employee {FirstName = "Elon", LastName = "Musk"},
        new Employee {FirstName = "Steve", LastName = "Jobs"},
        new Employee {FirstName = "Oprah", LastName = "Winfrey"},
        new Employee {FirstName = "Howard", LastName = "Schultz"},
        new Employee {FirstName = "Larry", LastName = "Ellison"},
        new Employee {FirstName = "Satya", LastName = "Nadella"},
    };
}
```

And your method could be named `GetEmployeeFirstAndLastNames`, and could be simplified a little if we use some `System.Linq` methods like `Select` (to select the concatenation of first and last name from each employee), and `OrderBy` (which will implicitly create a new list instead of us having to do it, and we can return it's result):

```
public static List<string> GetEmployeeFirstAndLastNames()
{
    PopulateEmployees();

    return employees.Select(e => e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName)
        .OrderBy(name => name)
        .ToList();
}
```

Usage example:

```
private static void Main()
{
    foreach (string name in GetEmployeeFirstAndLastNames())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]